# docker check if default seccomp profile is applied

Tags: linux, security, docker

I wish to know whether or not a specific docker container runs the default seccomp profile. I have no access to the command line which has been used to start the container, nor to the Dockerfile.

launching `ps aufxwww`, i can see that the process `/usr/bin/dockerd-current` has the options `--seccomp-profile=/etc/docker/seccomp.json`. This is indeed the default seccomp profile file.

However, the process `/usr/bin/docker-containerd-current`, launching the containerized application, has not. And `docker inspect` returns : `"SecurityOpt": null,`.

So which one do I trust ?

**EDIT**

More surprising, I have run a docker while explicitly specifying a seccomp filter

```
docker run -d --security-opt seccomp=/etc/docker/seccomp.python.json friendly
```

and the `/proc/$pid/status` file returns `seccomp 0`.

I would have expect instead, according to the man:

```
2 SECCOMP_MODE_FILTER
```

Comment: Many thanks for whoever +1 my question. However, this does not help me too much.

Answer (score 4):

I am not an expert and actually found this post because I googled the same question, but I found out this.

If you run Docker with a Seccomp profile, either by specifying nothing and docker will use the default, or by specifying a profile yourself in `daemon.json` or command line, and you run:

```
docker run -it alpine /bin/sh
/ # grep Seccomp /proc/1/status
Seccomp:        2
```

As you can see, you do get to see that the Seccomp filter is on inside the docker. 
If you explicitly tell docker to run with no Seccomp profile, you get 0.

```
docker run -it --security-opt seccomp=unconfine alpine /bin/sh
/ # grep Seccomp /proc/1/status
Seccomp:        0
```

So you can see it from inside the docker. Maybe this makes sense since it is the processes inside the Docker that needs to be confined by the Seccomp profile.

You can also test that a profile does something by [downloading the default profile](https://raw.githubusercontent.com/moby/moby/master/profiles/seccomp/default.json) and removing something from it, e.g. `chown`, and then try:

```
docker run -it --security-opt seccomp=/etc/docker/myseccomp.json alpine /bin/sh
/ # touch testfile
/ # chown 100.100 testfile
chown: testfile: Operation not permitted
```

Finally, according to the [man page](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/seccomp.2.html) it looks like from kernel 4.14 you can see something in:

```
/proc/sys/kernel/seccomp/actions_avail
```

This does not exist in my 4.9 kernel. I hope this is helpful to someone.